# Who should we study with?

Tags: torah-study

A standard teaching is having me a little confused:

> עֲשֵׂה לְךָ רַב -- Make for yourself a teacher. [Avot 1:6]

At first blush, it means: Find yourself a learned rabbi, as great as possible, to teach you Torah.  But the Rambam says it refers only to a study partner -- *any* study partner, even one who knows less than you do:

> [Make for yourself a teacher] means [make him play that role] even if he is not fit to be your mentor.  Place him upon you as a mentor, so that you can discuss and argue with him.  As a result of this, wisdom will come into your hand. If a man studies on his own, it is good; but if he studies with someone else, the teaching will be better established in his hand and it will be clearer -- even if his partner is like him or even below him in wisdom.

The Talmud emphasizes that point:

> Rav Naḥman bar Yitzḥak said: Why are Torah matters likened to a tree, as it is stated [in Proverbs]: "It is a tree of life to them that hold it fast." [Proverbs 3:18] ?  Because just as a small piece of wood can ignite a large piece, so too, minor Torah scholars can sharpen great Torah scholars.  And this is what Rabbi Ḥanina said: I have learned much from my teachers and even more from my peers, but from my students most of all. [Taanit 7a]

Does all this imply that

(1) It is *better* to study with someone who is "below you in wisdom" or just that

(2) You should study *with someone else* -- the more learned the better, but even if he isn't learned it's better than to study alone?

Comment: 1) might not follow; minor students _can_ sharpen great Torah scholars. It's not guaranteed

Comment: The Rambam is saying if you cannot find a real Rav, make one for yourself. The Gemara is saying there is a benefit to teaching. Both are true.

Comment: @N.T. -- Both are true all right, but which is *better*?  Some say "If you want to learn, teach."  (Because you study much more intensely when you have to teach.)

Comment: Why does one have to be better? Naturally, you have to learn before you can teach.